# Keras Out of memory with small batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I built an autoencoder using just tensorflow libraries with a network shape of:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 168, 120, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 60480)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              61932544
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 256)               262400
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              263168
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 60480)             61992000
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 168, 120, 3)       0
=================================================================
Total params: 124,450,112
Trainable params: 124,450,112
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

In the project just using tensorflow, I was able to train using my GPUs with no problem, with a batch size of 128. I wanted to recreate the autoencoder with just keras, and I run into an out of memory exception even with a batch size of one. From researching the problem, I've found that the best solution to this problem is to reduce the batch size, but I can't reduce it any further. My machine has 2 GTX 970 cards running in SLI (CUDA doesn't care about SLI) for a total of 8GB of memory. Why would I not be able to train this network with keras, even though I was able to train the same one with 64x the batch size using tensorflow?

Here is the relevant code:

Constants:

```
# Constants

WIDTH = 120
HEIGHT = 168
CHANNELS = 3
NUM_INPUTS = WIDTH*HEIGHT*CHANNELS
BATCH_SIZE=1
NUM_SAMPLES=5000
VALIDATION_SIZE=1
VALIDATION_SAMPLES=100
EPOCHS=1000

HIDDEN_WIDTH = 1024
ENCODING_WIDTH = 256

INPUT_PATH = './input/'
VALIDATION_PATH = './validation/'
MODEL_PATH = './model/'

MODEL_FILE = 'my_model.h5'
EPOCH_FILE = 'initial_epoch.txt'
```

Initialization and save:

```
# this is our input placeholder
input_img = Input(shape=(constants.HEIGHT,constants.WIDTH,constants.CHANNELS))
# flatten image into one dimension
flatten = Flatten()(input_img)
# hidden layer 1
hidden = Dense(constants.HIDDEN_WIDTH, activation='relu')(flatten)
# "encoded" is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = Dense(constants.ENCODING_WIDTH, activation='relu')(hidden)
# hidden layer 3
hidden = Dense(constants.HIDDEN_WIDTH, activation='relu')(encoded)
# "decoded" is the lossy reconstruction of the input
decoded = Dense(constants.NUM_INPUTS, activation='relu')(hidden)
# reshape to image dimensions
reshape = Reshape((constants.HEIGHT,constants.WIDTH,constants.CHANNELS))(decoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input_img, reshape)

autoencoder.summary()

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(data_format='channels_last',
                                   rescale=1./255)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(data_format='channels_last',
                                  rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        constants.INPUT_PATH, 
        target_size=(constants.HEIGHT,constants.WIDTH),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='input',
        batch_size=constants.BATCH_SIZE)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        constants.VALIDATION_PATH, 
        target_size=(constants.HEIGHT,constants.WIDTH),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='input',
        batch_size=constants.VALIDATION_SIZE)


autoencoder.fit_generator(train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=constants.NUM_SAMPLES*1.0/constants.BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs=1,
        verbose=2,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=constants.VALIDATION_SAMPLES*1.0/constants.VALIDATION_SIZE)


# Creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
autoencoder.save(constants.MODEL_PATH+constants.MODEL_FILE)
with open(constants.MODEL_PATH+constants.EPOCH_FILE, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(1))

print("Done, model created in: " + constants.MODEL_PATH)
```

Part of the error log:

```
2019-01-29 16:40:10.522222: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] ***********************************************************************************************_____
2019-01-29 16:40:10.525191: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at matmul_op.cc:478 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[60480,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "init.py", line 53, in <module>
    validation_steps=constants.VALIDATION_SAMPLES*1.0/constants.VALIDATION_SIZE)
  File "C:\Users\dekke\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dekke\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\dekke\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 217, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\dekke\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1217, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "C:\Users\dekke\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\dekke\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "C:\Users\dekke\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\dekke\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1024,60480] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/dense_4/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/dense_4/MatMul_grad/MatMul"], transpose_a=true, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](dense_3/Relu, training/Adam/gradients/dense_4/Relu_grad/ReluGrad)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

Comment: Just to make sure, did you run your `keras` model **after** clearing `tensorflow` model?

Comment: I'm not running them in the same session, do I need to forcefully clear the tensorflow model before the execution is done?

Comment: I didn't mean the same session. Unless you do something to limit gpu usage, or close the `tensorflow` session, it will occupy **all** gpus. Is the session you ran `tf` still alive?

Comment: No, it is not still alive.

Comment: @Glen654, you have 100 million parameters. VGG16 has similar no of parameters like you do. What you are trying here is to the effect of training VGG16 from scratch with 8 GB of total memory over 2 cards, which may be why you are running in to issues. Have you constructed this model the same way that you did in your successful tensorflow implementation, including the same no of parameters?

Comment: Yes. it's the exact same model dimensions, and I had no problem training the network up to a certain point. I'm migrating my code to keras, and plan to deploy on sagemaker.

Answer (score 3):

I get this from time to time using anaconda tf_gpu package with keras. I think you are either exhausting your free memory via python scripts, or tensorflow-gpu is trying to allocate a ton of memory at once:

I usually throw this under my imports and it works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config = config)

# Check available GPU devices.
print("The following GPU devices are available: %s" % tf.test.gpu_device_name())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not using using a tensorflow session, I am just calling .fit_generator, is there a way to use allow_growth with just keras? I remember using that in my tensorflow model.

Comment: Hey Glen yes. I believe so. If you are using jupyter notebook throw that under your imports at the initial cell.

Comment: I'm running this locally right now, but I'm writing this to run on a jupyter notebook with the full dataset when I can get it working.

Comment: Id give it a try. But your network size looks pretty big so it could be that. let me know how it works for you.

Comment: I found some code that would access the underlying tensorflow session, but I'm still getting the same result. Any other ideas? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Im not sure but.. im still fairly new at this as well. I don't want to give you Information that could potentially lead you astray. If you could reduce the network size id try that.